# Authentication, session redirect problem for nginx and php-fpm TCP

Tags: php, docker, nginx, fastcgi

I have transfered docker-compose project to ECS

I have two containers `php-fpm` which has `laravel` source and `nginx` in `ECS`

in docker-compose it uses `fastcgi` protocol

However in ECS both containers connect with `127.0.0.1:9000`

nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xxx.example.is;
  index  index.php index.html index.htm;
  root /var/www/public;
  client_max_body_size 200M; 

  location / {
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass php:9000 # for docker-compose

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
 }
```

in `php-fpm` container, `zzz-docker.conf`

```
[global]
daemonize = no

[www]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
#listen = 9000 # for docker compose
```

Now I access to the top page `/`, login form is appeared correctly,

Then when I put username and password and submit, it should be redirect `/home`

However, it comes back to `/` either correct ID/password or uncorrect ID/password

It looks like redirect is ignored.

This doesn't happen when using `fastcgi` protocol to communicate containers(in docker-compose)

So, I have questions.

Do I need to do something more when connection with TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 ?

Or is there anything else I need to check??

PHP log is here below

```
127.0.0.1 -  03/Jun/2022:18:23:29 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
127.0.0.1 -  03/Jun/2022:18:23:38 +0000 "POST /index.php" 302
127.0.0.1 -  03/Jun/2022:18:23:38 +0000 "GET /index.php" 302
127.0.0.1 -  03/Jun/2022:18:23:39 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
```

Database connection is correct. I have checked with the `laravel` tools.

```
root@ip-172-31-14-37:/var/www# php artisan tinker
PHP Warning: Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Psy Shell v0.11.2 (PHP 7.4.29 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> DB::select('select 1');
=> [
   {#3511
    +"1": 1,
   },
  ]
```

**I compared the login-procedure by chrome network console**

Somehow wrong one Response Header connection is `close`

One works well in localhost with `docker-compose` 
and another fails in `ECS`

docker-compose is login -> home

ECS is login -> home -> login

Correct step1
[image]

Correct step2
[image]

Wrong step1
[image]

Wrong step2
[image]

Comment: There is a lot of things you [could add to your nginx](https://pastebin.com/zVN8uJ9u) to improve security. I've added comments to each section, you can pick out what you like. This works for me when I span up a docker container, I re-ordered the `fastcgi` for readability - shouldn't have any effect AFAIK but potentially worth trying. Best of luck figuring it out, I don't know ECS Fargate but it doesn't seem like a `nginx` issue. You're hitting `php-fpm` perfectly fine.

Comment: @Jaquarh Thank you for your comment! .I have tried your security-setting, it works well.  I see that my problem is not on `nginx`.. Where should I start debugging....

Comment: Not entirely sure, sorry. The `302` looks like it come from your application, are you 100% sure it cannot serve any pages? Try set-up a test URI.

Comment: @Jaquarh, I added the test page showing database columns, then it works, so ,, the problem occurs only when authentications.....

Comment: How exactly is your app authenticating? Are you using basic auth? If so, perhaps you missing the header needed (or it is being dropped in the request)

Comment: I think I am using the basic auth, now I checked the response of both (correct and wrong one) in chrome network tab. i updated the article.

Comment: This is because of secure mode of PHP , so I use `https` it solves. `https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.ini.php` thank you for your help. I can debug step by step to the answer thanks to your comment.